# Create pandas dataframe from series with ordered dict as rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series, ordereddictionary, lmfit

I am trying to extract `lmfit` parameter results as dataframes. I pass 1 column `x`, 1 column `data` through a `fit_func` and parameters `pars` and the output of the `minimize` function in `lmfit` outputs as OrderedDict.

```
out = minimize(fit_func, pars, method = 'leastsq', args=(x, data))
res = out.params.valuesdict()
res
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('a1', 12.850309404600393),
             ('c1', 1346.833513206811),
             ('s1', 44.22337472274829),
             ('f1', 1.1275639898142586),
             ('a2', 77.15732669480884),
             ('c2', 1580.5712512351947),
             ('s2', 16.239969775527275),
             ('f2', 0.8684363668111492)])
```

The output I want in DataFrames I achieved like this with `pd.DataFrame(res,index=[0])` :
[image: desired_out]

I have 3 data columns that I want to quickly fit:

```
x = d.iloc[:,0]
fit_odict = pd.DataFrame(d.iloc[:,1:4].\
                         apply(lambda y: minimize(fit_func, pars, method = 'leastsq', args=(x, y))\
                        .params.valuesdict()),index=[1])
```

But I get a series of Ordered Dicts as rows in the Dataframe:

[image: out_2]

How do I get the output I want with the three parameter results as rows ? Is there a better way to apply the function?

**UPDATE:**

Appended @M Newville in my solution. Might be helpful for those who want to quickly extract `lmfit` parameter results from multiple data columns `d1.iloc[:,1:]` :

```
def fff(cols):
    out = minimize(fit_func, pars, method = 'leastsq', args=(x, cols))
    return {key: par.value for key, par in out.params.items()}

results = d1.iloc[:,1:].apply(fff,result_type='expand').transpose()
```

Output:

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

For a single fit, this would probably be what you are looking for:

```
out = minimize(fit_func, pars, method = 'leastsq', args=(x, data))
fit_odict = pd.DataFrame({key: [par.value] for key, par in out.params.items()})
```

I think you probably are looking for something like this:

```
results = {key: [] for key in pars}
for data in datasets:
    out = minimize(fit_func, pars, method='leastsq', args=(x, data))
    for par_name, val_list in results.items():
        val_list.append(out.params[par_name].value)
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

You could probably stuff that all into a single long line, but I wouldn't recommend it -- someone may want to read that code ;).

Comment: Hi! This worked for me! But it did take a long time to calculate 400 `datasets` columns (assuming its the nested for-loops). Would there be a faster way to perform this? I might not have been clear that the 400 to-be-fitted columns are already in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Hud in principle, you can do the 400 fits in parallel. An individual fit cannot be parallelized easily itself, but you can use the multiprocessing module to do each fit in a separate process and on a separate CPU core.  You may not have 400 cores, but it would help even to have 4 or 8 cores working at a time.  FWIW, the actual fit will take all the actual runtime, so it won't matter if the data is in pandas dataframes or numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick work around that you can do. The code is not efficient but you can optimize it. Note that index start 1 but you are welcome to re-index using pandas library

```
import pandas as pd

# Your output is a list of tuple
OrderedDict = [('a1', 12.850309404600393),('c1', 1346.833513206811),('s1', 
44.22337472274829),('f1', 1.1275639898142586),('a2', 77.15732669480884),('c2', 
1580.5712512351947),('s2', 16.239969775527275),('f2', 0.8684363668111492)]

# Create a dataframe from the list of tuple and tanspose
df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict).T
# Get the first row for the dataframe columns namea
columns = df.loc[0].values.tolist()
df.columns = columns
output = df.drop(df.index[0])
output

    a1      c1      s1      f1      a2      c2      s2      f2
1   12.8503 1346.83 44.2234 1.12756 77.1573 1580.57 16.24   0.868436
```